# FaultException when using ExecuteTransactionRequest (CRM 2015)

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm doing a bit of a technical investigation into the ExecuteTransactionRequest. It's not something I've ever used before so I knocked up a very quick experiment just to see how it works. However, when sending off the request the OrganizationService is throwing back a FaultException (below). What I believe is happening is that my version of CRM doesn't support that OrganizationRequest. Although I'm pretty sure I have the right assemblies and version.

Can anyone please shed some light on what I'm missing?

**CRM Deployment Version:** 7.0.1.129

**Organization Version:** 7.0.2.53

**Microsoft.Xrm Assembly Version:** 7.0.0.0 (Also happened with 8.0.0.0)

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll
>
> Additional information: The formatter threw an exception while trying
>   to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to
>   deserialize parameter
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:request. The
>   InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 451. Element
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:request'
>   contains data from a type that maps to the name
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts:ExecuteTransactionRequest'.
>   The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your
>   DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name
>   'ExecuteTransactionRequest' and namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts'.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

```cs
CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse(GetCrmConnectionString("unmanaged"));
IOrganizationService orgService = new OrganizationService(connection);

ExecuteTransactionRequest transactionRequest = new ExecuteTransactionRequest()
{
    ReturnResponses = true,
    Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
};

Entity newContact = new Entity("contact");
newContact["firstname"] = "Stack";
newContact["lastname"] = "Overflow";

CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest()
{
    Target = newContact
};

transactionRequest.Requests.Add(createRequest);

ExecuteTransactionResponse transactionResponse = (ExecuteTransactionResponse)orgService.Execute(transactionRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Quick look at your code, looked like it was because of the `CreateRequest` not being added to the collection. After your comments and double checking the crm organization version, you are on CRM 2015 (not on update 1). [ExecuteTransactionRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executetransactionrequest.aspx) is only supported by CRM 2015 update 1 (version 7.1.XXX) and up (version 8.0.XXX) organizations. So unfortunately, your query won't work until at least the 2015 update is applied to the organization.

---

You did not add your create request to the `ExecuteTransactionRequest` - `Requests` collection. An empty request collection is causing the exceptions most likely.

```cs
ExecuteTransactionRequest transactionRequest = new ExecuteTransactionRequest()
{
     ReturnResponses = true,
     Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
};

Entity newContact = new Entity("contact");
newContact["firstname"] = "Stack";
newContact["lastname"] = "Overflow";

CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest()
{
     Target = newContact
};

transactionRequest.Requests.Add(createRequest); //missing

ExecuteTransactionResponse transactionResponse = (ExecuteTransactionResponse)orgService.Execute(transactionRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks for the spot. That was just because I refactored the code a bit to make it more Stack friendly and forgot to add it back in. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: So you still get an error even after adding the create request to the transaction request's request collection?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately

Comment: Updated my answer. Not supported by your organization version (just 2015 and not update 1)